# Get some properties from an object and nested object

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection, lambda

I'd like return an object (`ExpandoObject`) with only the fields and nested fields received by the method.

```
var fieldsToGet = new List<string> { "FirstName", "Id"};
```

When I do this :

```
.Select(x => Helpers.FilteringProperties(x, fieldsToGet))
```

I receive an object with this two values, that's work.
I receive an object with `FirstName` and `Id`

Now I'd like return some properties of the nested object :

```
var fieldsToGet = new List<string> { "FirstName", "Id", "Language.Name"};
```

I'd like receive these properties :
`FirstName`, `Id` and `Language.Name`

The code below works but I'd like stay generic enough and be able to manage the nested.

How can I do this generic, managed the nested object ?

Thanks,

The current code :

```
public static object FilteringProperties(object employee, List<string> fields)
{
    if (!fields.Any())
        return employee;
    else
    {
        ExpandoObject result = new ExpandoObject();
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            var fieldValue = employee.GetType()
            .GetProperty(field, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .GetValue(employee, null);

            ((IDictionary<String, Object>)result).Add(field, fieldValue);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Sample classes :

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Language Language { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could do a split on the "."-character, get the Property with that name, and then get its value by calling your own function recursively.

Something like this (pseudo-code, can be a lot better)

```
if (field.Contains(".")) {
   var parts = field.Split('.');
   var fieldName = parts[0];
   List<string> toGet = new List<string>();
   toGet.Add(parts[1]); // this now contains everything after the "." 

   var fieldValue = employee.GetType()
        .GetProperty(fieldName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .GetValue(employee, null);

   ((IDictionary<String, Object>)result).Add(field, FilteringProperties(fieldValue, toGet)
}
```

Comment: You must change `.GetProperty(field, ` to `.GetProperty(fieldName, `, and `FilteringProperties(fieldValue, toGet)` to `((IDictionary<String, Object>)result).Add(field, FilteringProperties(fieldValue, toGet)`

Comment: Well noticed, Xanatos! Thanks, I've updated my post.

Comment: In my exemple the nested object is one level but can be more.

Answer (score 0):

Using a recursive approach. I'm sure it can be improved.

```
public static object FilteringProperties(object employee, List<string> fields)
{
    if (!fields.Any())
        return employee;
    else
    {
        ExpandoObject result = new ExpandoObject();
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            object fieldValue = null;

            Regex regex = new Regex("(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)");
            Match match = regex.Match(field);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                string className = match.Groups[1].Value;
                string propertyName = match.Groups[2].Value;

                var o = FilteringProperties(employee.GetType().GetProperty(className).GetValue(employee, null), new List<string>() {propertyName});
                var entry = (IDictionary<string, object>) o;
                fieldValue = entry[propertyName];
            }

            if(fieldValue == null)
                fieldValue = employee.GetType()
                .GetProperty(field, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .GetValue(employee, null);

            ((IDictionary<String, Object>)result).Add(field, fieldValue);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work for me -

```
public static ExpandoObject CreateObject(object parent, List<string> fields)
    {
        var expando = new ExpandoObject();
        var ret = (IDictionary<string,object>)expando;

        foreach (var property in fields)
        {
            //split to determine if we are a nested property.
            List<string> properties = property.Split('.').ToList();
            if (properties.Count() > 1)
            {
                //get our 'childs' children - ignoring the first item 
                var grandChildren = properties.Skip(1);

                //copy this child object and use it to pass back into this method recusivly - thus creating our nested structure
                var child = parent.GetType().GetProperty(properties[0]).GetValue(parent, null);
                //passing in the child object and then its children - which are grandchildren from our parent.
                ret.Add(properties[0], CreateObject(child, grandChildren.ToList()));
            }
            else //no nested properties just assign the property 
                ret.Add(property, parent.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(parent));
        }

        return expando;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marc - guru from this site - I came up with the following approach:

```
public static object GetFlattenPropertyValue(this object source, string flattenPropertyName) {

    var expression = source.GetType().CreatePropertyExpression(flattenPropertyName);

    if (expression != null) {
        var getter = expression.Compile();
        return getter.DynamicInvoke(source);
    }

    return null;
}

public static LambdaExpression CreatePropertyExpression(this Type type, string flattenPropertyName) {

    if (flattenPropertyName == null) {
        return null;
    }

    var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
    Expression body = param;
    foreach (var member in flattenPropertyName.Split('.')) {
        body = Expression.PropertyOrField(body, member);
    }

    return Expression.Lambda(body, param);
}
```